# Javascript advent calendar, trouble with finding date/month

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am back with another newbie question! :) I'am trying to use a advent-calendar I found here: https://github.com/tpowell/jsadvent . It is set up for demo use, so that the the first door can be opened even if its not december. I got that working well. But when I try to make it check the date itself, all doors gets available what ever I try. Below is the code that (I think) checks the date:

```
(function($) {
    /** CALENDAR ACTION **********/
    // Sets Action on calendar click
    // Example with default overrides: $('ul.component-calendar').PINT_calendar({date:12 });
    $.fn.PINT_calendar = function(options) {
        /** USER ADDED SETTINGS ( Pass into function/method call init ) **/
        var settings = $.extend({
            // Defaults
            date: 1, //new Date().getDate(); Set Limit Day ( all days before this selectable )
            month: 12, //new Date().getMonth()+1; Sets which month to set this up for (i.e.     December)
            fadeTiming: 300, // When you hover on a calendar day, this is the 'fade' animation speed
            daySlideDuration: 500 // When you click a calendar day, this is the 'slide' animation     speed
        }, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var calendar = $(this);
            calendar.find('li').each(function() {
                if (settings.month == 12 && settings.date >= parseInt($(this).find('.day').text(), 10)) {
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                }
            });
```

The 2 lines where it says date:1 and month12 is where I think I'm supposed to remove the 2 slashes and the date:1 and month12, so that those lines begins with 
    new Date().getDate() and new Date().getMonth(). 
Well, I tried this and it does not work. The code is originally from 2011, could it be that the script opens all doors because it is 2014 now? I've tried to find anything about the year, but can't find anything. Or am I just doing things wrong? Is there someone out there that knows what schould be done to make this code check date itself?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: I made it work! It was me ending the date and month lines with semicolons, instead of commas like the defaults. Thanks for the push! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've actually tried that one not so long ago.

You have to set the date manually every day as far as i've read on their facebook :(

I've been trying to get / make a working advent calendar for roughly too weeks now and i can't for the life of me figure it out haha

Comment: @ Michel This worked for me:
`code`date:new Date().getDate(),
`code`month:new Date().getMonth()+1,
`code`fadeTiming:300, // When you hover on a calendar day, this is the 'fade' animation speed
`code`daySlideDuration:500 // When you click a calendar day, this is the 'slide' animation speed

Comment: Dude its totally working ! (took my noobness a while to understand)
Thanks man !!!